# Returned value from Meteor Helper not showing up in template

Tags: meteor

I have a Meteor Helper that does a GET request and am supposed to get response back and pass it back to the Template, but its now showing up the front end. When I log it to console, it shows the value corerctly, for the life of mine I can't get this to output to the actual template.

Here is my helper:

```
 UI.registerHelper('getDistance', function(formatted_address) {
HTTP.call( 'GET', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?    units=imperial&origins=Washington,DC&destinations='+formatted_address+'&key=MYKEY', {}, function( error, response ) {
if ( error ) {
console.log( error );
} else {
var distanceMiles = response.data.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
console.log(response.data.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text);
return distanceMiles;
}
});
});
```

In my template I pass have the following:

```
{{getDistance formatted_address}}
```

Again, this works fine and shows exactly what I need in the console, but not in the template.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted an [article](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/using-meteor-local-collections-to-support-browser-based-cryptography) on TMC recently that you may find useful for such a pattern. In that article the problem involves executing an expensive function for each item in a list. As others have pointed out, doing asynchronous calls in a helper is not good practice.

In your case, make a local collection called `Distances.` If you wish, you can use your document `_id` to align it with your collection.

```
const Distances = new Mongo.collection(); // only declare this on the client
```

Then setup a function that either lazily computes the distance or returns it immediately if it's already been computed:

```
function lazyDistance(formatted_address){
  let doc = Distances.findOne({ formatted_address: formatted_address });
  if ( doc ){
    return doc.distanceMiles;
  } else {      
    let url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json';
    url += '?units=imperial&origins=Washington,DC&key=MYKEY&destinations=';
    url += formatted_address;
    HTTP.call('GET',url,{},(error,response )=>{
      if ( error ) {
        console.log( error );
      } else {
        Distances.insert({
          formatted_address: formatted_address,
          distanceMiles: response.data.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Now you can have a helper that just returns a cached value from that local collection:

```
UI.registerHelper('getDistance',formatted_address=>{
  return lazyDistance(formatted_address);
});
```

You could also do this based on an `_id` instead of an address string of course. There's a tacit assumption above that `formatted_address` is unique.

It's Meteor's *reactivity* that really makes this work. The first time the helper is called the distance will be null but as it gets computed asynchronously the helper will automagically update the value.

Comment: Wow this is a real cool way to do this, I can't believe I didn't see that you replied until now.

Answer (score 1):

best practice is not to do an async call in a helper. think of the #each and the helper as a way for the view to simply show the results of a prior calculation, not to get started on doing the calculation. remember that a helper might be called multiple times for a single item.

instead, in the onCreated() of your template, start the work of getting the data you need and doing your calculations. store those results in a reactive var, or reactive array. then your helper should do nothing more than look up the previously calculated results. further, should that helper be called more times than you expect, you don't have to worry about all those additional async calls being made.

Answer (score 0):

The result does not show up because HTTP.call is an async function.

Use a reactiveVar in your case.

Depending on how is the formated_address param updated you can trigger the getDistance with a tracker autorun.

Regs
Yann

Comment: can I still do this even though this needs to run multiple times? Meaning I have an {{#each restaurant}}  statement and am trying to calculate the distance from user to each of the restaurants. Are you recommending to just put save a reactive var as the result of http.get in the tracker?